# Changed connection string but mvc application still using localdb

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I changed my connection string in the web.config to use sqlexpress rather than just localdb. My app still creates the database in localdb rather than in sqlexpress. I'm stumped.

Here is my connection string

`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Jemco;Integrated Security=True;`

Could it be something with my app.config?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Entity framework code first? Look at (or post it here) the line where you initialize the DataContext.

Comment: Yes, I'm using entity framework code first. I use a Unit Of Work and a Repository to work with the database but there's nothing to do with a connection in there. Maybe I'm not understanding your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">` instead of the `LocalDbConnectionFactory` and also adding the connection string amongst its `<parameters>` tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"> 
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=Jemco;" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

The < defaultConnectionFactory > element settings only apply when you have supplied no 'hints' to Entity Framework.

You can override the DbContext base class constructor to supply 'hints' to Entity Framework. Assuming you are defining your connection string in the .config file all you need to do is have your YOUR_DbContext class call the base DbContext(string) constructor supplying your connection string name, add the below public constructor to your DbContext class

```
 public class YOUR_DbContext : DbContext{

    public YOUR_DbContext()
        : base("**YOUR_ConnectionStringNameHere**"){
        //Optional - Write the actual connect string out to the Output window 
        Debug.WriteLine(Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One other reasons for this could be when you have several projects on a solution and you chose a project as start up project other than the project your DBContext is and you did not set the connection string in the start up project.Just set the connection string in the start up project as well.

Hope help someone ;)