# Change connection string in EF from localDB to SQL Server instance

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I don't want to use localdb when debugging my ASP.NET MVC project. When I used the database-first wizard to create the model, it correctly connected to my SQL Server instance. However, any time I run my project locally (F5), it's connecting to the localdb.

How do I use my SQL Server instance instead of localdb when running my project in debug locally?

I have tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315202/changed-connection-string-but-mvc-application-still-using-localdb).

web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-hpmvc-20151014093518.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-hpmvc-20151014093518;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="MyConnectionStringName" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer\MyNamedInstance;initial catalog=MyDatabase;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
...
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="MyConnectionStringName" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
```

And `DbContext`:

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities() : base("MyConnectionStringName")
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

And yet, when I run debug on the Index view, I'm seeing the test records in localdb and not the records in my SQL Server instance.

Comment: You are adding that conn string in the config of the web app you are executing, right?. it just to make sure ;)

Comment: @octavioccl - yes.

Comment: check the web.Debug.config file the connection should be to sql server not local db

Comment: @CyberProgs - The only connection string in the Debug config is the default one (name = "MyDB")  that's been commented out.  I tried adding my SQL Server connection string, and it's still connecting to localdb.